# Java compiler wrongly marks varible as might already have been assigned to

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, javac, final

For some reason java compiler marks the lower str variable as "might already have been assigned to" although this scenario is not possible (at least so I think).
any idea why?
I know removing the final modifier will solve it but I would like to understand the reason...

```
final List<Long> idList = List.of(1L,2L,3L);
final String str;
boolean found = false;
for (Long id : idList) {
   if (id == 2) {
      str = "id" + id;
      found = true;
      break;
   }
}

if (!found) {
   str = "none";
}
```

using java 15 on intelliJ IDE

Comment: The compiler does not understand the relationship between the first assignment to str and the setting of found to true.

Comment: Well, the compiler won't check your logic so it must assume that you could end up in a situation where  `str` was assigned multiple times. Note that even though your code seems to be simple enough to grasp on a glance the compiler would have to be able to handle much more complex situations which could take a while and still be wrong. So it has to draw a line somewhere ... and your code already crosses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule about not being able to assign to final variables more than once, written more formally (JLS [4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)):

> It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned immediately prior to the assignment.

The Java Language Specification spends the whole [chapter 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-16.html) talking about what counts as "definitely assigned" and "definitely unassigned". A variable can be either "definitely assigned" or "definitely unassigned", *both*, or *neither*.

In this case, if you apply the rules about for loops on your code, you will see that there is only one rule that talks about the definite [un]assignment after for loop:

> - V is [un]assigned after a for statement iff both of the following are true:
>
>   - Either a condition expression is not present or V is [un]assigned after the condition expression when false.
>   - V is [un]assigned before every break statement for which the for statement is the break target.

Let's try to show that `str` is definitely unassigned after the for loop.

In a enchanted for loop, there is obviously a condition expression (checks if the iterator `hasNext`). The condition doesn't involve `str`, so `str` stays unassigned as before. We meet the first bullet point. `str` *is* assigned before the break though, so we don't meet the second bullet point.

We cannot show that `str` is definitely unassigned after the for loop using the rules in chapter 16. (In fact we can't show it is assigned after the for loop either, but that's rather irrelevant.) The `if (!found)` statement isn't doing any assignment either, so this means that `str` is *not* definitely unassigned before `str = "none";`. Hence the compiler error according to 4.12.4.

If you still want to use a final variable, Try using a basic for loop to get the index of the found element, then assign it to `str`:

```
final List<Long> idList = List.of(1L,2L,3L);
final String str;
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
  Long id = idList.get(i);
  if (id == 2) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}
if (index < 0) {
  str = "none";
} else {
  str = "id" + idList.get(index);
}
```

Alternatively, use streams:

```
final String str = 
    idList.stream()
        .filter(x -> x == 2)
        .findFirst()
        .map(x -> "id" + x)
        .orElse("none");
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not going to do a deep analysis on your code to figure it out. It would take a long time, and (see Halting Problem), perfection is literally mathematically unattainable.

Thus, instead, the compiler has a simple list of operations it applies.

In this case, the `str =`  assignment is in an `if` which is in a `while` loop, so, it can run 0 times, 1 time, or many times. It neither infers the property that `str` is set (could run 0 times), but also isn't allowed to touch a final variable (could run 2 times or more).

Answer (score -3):

Given the fact that str has the modifier final, the compiler looks at it, in this scenario as if str is a variable of type String that will has an ability to changes(given its a variable) to which the modifier final can not accept changes.